# Syslog user able to read file thanks to ACL but rsyslog process is not

Tags: acl, rsyslog

I configured some ACL to grant syslog user to read log files that are owned by root under 700 permission directories. I'm able to read them when i logon as syslog. Rsyslog is configured with $PrivDropToUser syslog.

I have this error when i restart rsyslog :

```
rsyslogd-2433: file '/var/log/containers/default-http-2250134485-3c78s_kube-system_default-http-c8723f65a7a7371374037d7d99abb99ac07d977c792edd79add695392853ba22.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.35.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
```

This log is a link to /var/lib/docker/containers/DOCKER_ID/DOCKER_ID-json.log

I don't want to mess with kubernetes/docker ownership, that's why i tried with ACL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, one of my acl wasn't correctly set and it was only working for the file I was testing....